# Questions Lost in the Shuffle

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

I was just wondering if there is an acceptable way to prevent one's questions from getting lost in the shuffle.  I just asked a question on Stack Overflow 30 minutes ago, and it is now appearing on page 5 of the Questions.  Is there a way to bump one's questions?  Does commenting on or editing your question help get a question bumped?  I do not have the reputation yet to post a bounty, and I'm not sure if you can upvote your own questions...  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Using a good title and putting in the appropriate tags is one the best ways to get good answers to your question. Many Stack Overflow users subscribe to tag-specific RSS feeds, so even if your question is not on the front page it does not matter as users will read it from the feed and post an answer.

Please do not edit your post unless you have new material/content to add in your original question.